How to store default cucumber report into a datetimestamp folder so that we can view them later if required?
I am using default cucumber report with below runner class in a cucumber-java project build with maven.
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/featureFiles", 
        glue = { "stepDefinations", "hooks" }, 
        plugin = {  "pretty",
                    "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.html",
                    "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"
                 }, 
        tags = "@latest", 
        monochrome = true, 
        dryRun = false)

public class RunTest {
    
}

I want to store the reports into a run time generated folder (say, 04-dec-2024-12-08-25) [generated at @BeforeAll method inside Hooks file].
NOTE: I have tried to copy the html report in @AfterAll method, but the complete html report file is not getting copied.
Thanks in advance

Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79002954/cucumber-java-dynamic-report-filename/79006457#79006457

Thanks @M.P.Korstanje, this post helps. However I need to format the maven build timestamp.

Check https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html under "Available Variables - Project Model Variables"
